# migrating facebook send Dialog parameters to openGraph changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following:

```js
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  to: connectionid,
  name: subject,
  picture: staticurl + 'images/logoformysite.png',
  link: homeurl + '/' + username + '/something=' + var1 +'&somethingelse=' + encodeURI(var2) + '&evenmore=' + encodeURI(var3),
  description: invitemessage,
});
```

Facebook is informing me this: 
`Send Dialog will use Open Graph meta tags and ignore 'name', 'description', and 'picture' parameters.`

If the button is showing multiple times on my page with different parameters, how should I set the `og.url` and `og.description` properties once on top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`og:url` is the URL of your current page, not the target. That's not a problem for such things.

Look at some news website with the [Facebook object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to understand how it is implemented.

Comment: Got it. But what about description and name? I need those to be personalized.

Comment: meta tags contain values related to the current page. If you talk about FB.ui parameters they will be ignored after the October 2 breaking change.

Comment: Look at my answer. Have a look at the [Open Graph Protocol](http://opengraphprotocol.org/) first.