# Facebook javascript send api error link invalid

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a referral application where users can refer their Facebook friends using a referral code. I'm using Facebook Javascript SDK. The problem I'm facing is that the send method works only for particular URLs, I mean if I change the users referral token in **link** parameter it gives me `error 100 invalid link.`

Here is the method :

```js
FB.init({appId: app_id, xfbml: true, cookie: true});

FB.ui({        
    to : '********',    
    method: 'send',    
    name: 'Message',    
    link: 'example.com/emp?token=fAiS1ywL0lS8cUYtgLjk',    
    redirect_uri:'http://example.com'   
});
```

For some particular link values it works fine but if the token is changed it fails with invalid link error.

I'm stuck with fixing this issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982183/facebook-fb-ui-send-dialog-intermittently-returns-invalid-link-error/)

Comment: Thanks. One more question what is og:url actually? The url of the page on which the script is written is different that the url in link I want to send. Then which URL should I specify in og:url meta tag?

Comment: I created an answer summarizing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Facebook FB.ui send dialog intermittently returns invalid link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982183/facebook-fb-ui-send-dialog-intermittently-returns-invalid-link-error/).

For your second question related to the `og:url` meta, to simplify you have to provide the URL of the current page.

The [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) says:

> og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its
>   permanent ID in the graph, e.g.,
>   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

To understand how those metas work you can check how News websites implement this with the [Facebook Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).
For example [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2013%2F08%2F08%2Fworld%2Fafrica%2Fhuge-fire-shuts-down-nairobis-international-airport.html%3Fhp%26_r%3D0) shows you the implemention of metas for a well-known newspaper website.

Comment: still having issues may be I'm not configuring url properly

Comment: suppose my homepage is www.example.com and I want to share link with url www.example.com/emp?token=1234. What should  be my og:url example.com or exmaple.com/emp? and on which page I need to mention og tags?. My questions may seem absurd but I'm a beginner. Please help.

Comment: Your URL should be `www.example.com/emp?token=1234` and your meta are on your target page(www.example.com/emp?token=1234). Look at [how the New-York Times do it in Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2013%2F08%2F08%2Fworld%2Fafrica%2Fhuge-fire-shuts-down-nairobis-international-airport.html%3Fhp%26_r%3D0)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the debugger, helped me solve my issue. FB needs to be able to scrape the url provided.

Comment: I have tried with Facebook Debugger..but no improvement. Still getting the same. Please advice me.

Comment: Yesterday you asked help in multiple solved questions. Just read the answer and try to fix it, otherwise please create a new question.